# Bulk API 2.0 v52.0 Query select *

Tags: query, bulk-api-v2

I'm trying to post the following json body to the Bulk Api endpoint but am getting an error.

```
{
  "operation": "query",
  "query": "SELECT * FROM Account"
}
```

error

```
[
    {
        "errorCode": "INVALIDJOB",
        "message": "Query parsing error: unexpected token: '*'"
    }
]
```

Is select * not allowed or am I just doing it wrong?

Comment: There's no "SELECT * FROM..." in Salesforce. Please go through [SOQL Tutorial](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/soql-for-admins/get-started-with-soql-queries)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce uses something called [Salesforce Object Query Language](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm), or SOQL for short.  SQL is not used in most cases, and the edge cases are from what I understand only applicable for certain things in [Marketing Cloud](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_using_the_query_activity.htm&type=5).

There is a decently recent addition to SOQL that's similar to using a `SELECT *` in SQL, which is `SELECT FIELDS(ALL)`, but unless you're using a where clause that matches on the ID (`WHERE Id = 'idgoeshere'`), you must specify a limit of 200 or less (more on `FIELDS()` [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_fields.htm)).  If you want more than that, you have to specify each field you want to retrieve.

I would follow @identigral's advice and brush up on the [SOQL Trailheads](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/soql-for-admins/get-started-with-soql-queries), and depending on what you're looking to do, [Data Loader](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/data_loader.htm) might be something to look into as well.